# Magnetism due to 3 infinetly long current-carrying wires mutually perpendicular to each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Same current is flowing in three infinitely long wires along positive $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions. The magnetic field at the point $(0,0,−a)$ would be?

Since we have to find magnetic field at negative $z$ axis, we only consider current due to x axis and y axis.

The magnetic field from the  $x$-axis wire is $$ \mathbf B^{(x)} = - {\mu I \over 2πa} \hat{j}.$$

The magnetic field from the  $y$-axis wire is $$ \mathbf B^{(y)} = + {\mu I \over 2πa} \hat{i}.$$

Therefore the net field is $$ \mathbf B = +{\mu I \over 2πa}( \hat{i}-\hat{j}).$$

But the answer states that it is along $\hat{j}-\hat{i}$. How?

Comment: How can the same current be flowing in three wires? That violates charge conservation (Kirchhoff). Am I missing something?

Comment: @CuriousOne The three wires don't connect to each other (despite passing through the same mathematical point :) ). They are separate 'circuits' (except, being infinitely long wires carrying currents, they are not circuits at all).

Comment: Charge conservation doesn't care about what happens at infinite, but it does care about what happens where the wires terminate at the origin. One can't just have current coming out of or disappearing in the origin... at least not in this universe. May I therefor conclude that this is either an out-of-this world physics problem or that whoever thought it up didn't care about posing a physical problem?

Comment: The wires don't terminate at the origin - they run from - to + infinity, as I understand the question.

Comment: If the wires are running from minus to plus infinity, then the field in (0,0-a) is not defined... you are sitting right on a singular current, that's why I assumed that they terminate in the origin. The problem would be well posed with only two wires... or one can make them of finite diameter with a well behaved current distribution and then eliminate the one we are sitting on by symmetry... in either case the problem sounds a bit forced.

Comment: The 3 wires do not form a circuit.They are 3 separate wires starting from the origin to + infinity

Comment: Such a system does not exist. Charge doesn't come out of nowhere. Now there is a good test for your teacher's attitude. If he/she doesn't give you double points for noticing that he/she/someone messed up, it's time to look for a new teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is just a matter of left handed vs right handed co-ordinate systems, and you are working with a different one to the question.[image]

The first image on the left is a right handed co-ordinate system. The middle one is a left handed co-ordinate system, and the final image is the left handed co-ordinate system rotated to the $x$ and $y$ axes are aligned as in the right handed system.

I hope it is pretty obvious that considering currents in the positive $x$ and positive $y$ directions (and ignoring the problematic $z$ current) that the $i$ and $j$ components of the magnetic field are going to have opposite signs in the two systems at a given $z$ position.

Comment: Thanks.You're right! The Cartesian system I chose was different.if u consider the middle diagram with the positive z pointing out of the paper and apply right hand rule u get (j-i)